# How do i access a hidden column value hidden by jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

in my JQUery `datatable` i have these columns with some other columns

```
columns: [
 {first column has a button}, 
{ 'data': 'ID', visible:false },
{ 'data': 'EmployeeCategoryID', visible: false }, other columns ...
]
```

the first column of the datatable has a button when i click on it it should display second hidden column value i have tried this

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text()
```

but the hidden columns are not accessible in this way.. how do i access the value of hidden columns?

In the original code the data comes from MVC action method and data was sent fine!

Comment: You need to load data related to the row and access the column in that data. Doesn't matter if it is hidden in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried, but something along these lines :

```
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetData(row);
    console.log(data);
```

Here example is your control name.

Comment: it comes as undefined or the button wouldnt work... typically with hidden columns in datatables, how do developers access those hidden columns?

Comment: can you access rowData ? try logging it in console. console.log(rowData);